# I am trying to change my login Jpanel to the main menu Jpanel but when I execute the program nothing appears on the screen

Tags: java, authentication, jpanel

I have a login system that goes to the main menu and from there you can do different things.
The problem is when I try go from the Log in screen to the main menu all that appears when I press the log in button is a blank screen.

Here is my code to change from the log in Jpanel to the main menu Jpanel

```
     if(loggedIn){
                  controlPanel.setVisible(false);
                  mainFrame.remove(controlPanel);
                  MainMenu MM = new MainMenu();
                  mainFrame.add(MM);
                  MM.setVisible(true);
            }
```

What is wrong with this code that the main menu doesn't appear when I log in

Comment: And where is the code where you add the new panel to your frame?

Comment: After changing the content of a container, the container must be revalidated before the change will show up.